# NuxtJS - Use asyncData method in layout or component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, asyncdata

How I can use `asyncData` in layout or component (*forbidden apparently*) ?

Because my sidebar component is used in default layout, and I need to use `asyncData` to display data from backend.
And if I use Vuex to fetch data... I don't know how I can fetch this with global on every page.

## My layout component annotation:

```
  @Component({
    components: {
      LeftDrawer
    },
    async asyncData({ app }) {
      const latestPosts = await app.$axios.get(`/posts/latest`);

      return {
        latestPosts: latestPosts.data,
      };
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

fetch and asyncData works only for pages, as it stated in [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/). If you need something to get data on each page, use [nuxtServerInit](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action)

```
actions: {
  async nuxtServerInit({ dispatch }) {
    await dispatch('core/load')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The new `fetch` on `Nuxt >= 2.12` now supports fetching on the `layout` and `component` level.

Right now it's slightly broken for me on the `layout` level for my statically generated site so I use `fetchOnServer: false`. By the time future people read this it'll hopefully be fixed, so feel free to edit this out.

Here's some useful reading material :)

[Docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/)

[General guide](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/understanding-how-fetch-works-in-nuxt-2-12)

[Guide for static sites](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/going-full-static/)

Comment: I am also noticing issues with `async fetch()` when combined with `target: "static"` in my Nuxt config. `fetchOnServer: false` fixes my issue for some components, but when applied to others, it breaks my build...Still troubleshooting.

Comment: Make another Stack Overflow question and tag me, I'll see if I can see something obvious. If not, you might need to make a Github issue.

Comment: Our current solution which my coworker found is to do `created() { this.$fetch(); }` I asked him about it and his theory is that in the server `mounted()` won't run until `created()` is done. Since we call the fetch API in the created lifecycle method, the data will be available when the mounted lifecycle method runs. The QA passed, so I am assuming this method works for our use case of fetching yaml translation files on build.

Comment: Glad you got it working, still worth making a Github issue so they they can either fix this or add it to the docs. Good luck with the rest of your project :)