# Using async fetch from layouts in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

On **pages/tags.vue** I am using this to fetch my api :

```
async fetch () {
        this.fetchresults = await this.$http.$get('https://api.domain/tags')
        this.tags = this.fetchresults.results;
  },
```

Its working fine but when I try to do the same thing from **layouts/default.vue** 90% of the time the **tags** is empty, its seem to only work once when I update my code then when I refresh **tags** is empty again. I cant use async fetch from the layout ?

Comment: duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58205391/nuxtjs-use-asynddata-method-in-layout-or-component

Comment: Thanks I saw that post but that really doesnt help, when I paste something on store/index.js I allways get a parse error.

Comment: try to use getters in layout

Comment: its ok I found the solution, I can use fetch() from components and its load fine if I do "fetchOnServer: false", its not SEO friendly but it work fine.